# where to write the AutoForm.addHooks() code to manipulate the submitted autoform values

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Below is the hook code that I want to use to manipulate the submitted values from QuickForm.

```
var hooksObject = {
  before: {
    insert: function(doc) {
      console.log(doc);
      return doc;
    }
  }
};

AutoForm.addHooks('insertBankDetailForm', hooksObject, true);
```

I have read the docs and it says "*These calls should be anywhere in top-level client code and do not need to be within Meteor.startup. You should not put them in an autorun, template rendered function, or anywhere else where they will be called multiple times since that will cause the hooks to run multiple times for a single submission.*"

I tried placing the code most of the places, but I am unable to understand the location where it need to be kept. I get below error when I use above code in `index.js` at location `D:\PROJECT\imports\startup\client\index.js`

```
Error: Oops! Did you forget to return the modified document from your docToForm hook for the insertBankDetailForm form?
    at autoFormEachDocToForm (aldeed_autoform.js?hash=62240ad…:6595)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (underscore.js?hash=cde485f…:149)
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (aldeed_autoform.js?hash=62240ad…:6592)
    at blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:1934
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:3744)
    at blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:1932
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:2271)
    at viewAutorun (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:1931)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js?hash=997515f…:339)
meteor.js?hash=27829e9…:930 Exception from Tracker recompute function:
meteor.js?hash=27829e9…:930 TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMembers' of undefined
    at doMaterialize (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:2093)
    at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (tracker.js?hash=997515f…:640)
    at Blaze.View.doRender (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:2090)
    at blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:1934
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:3744)
    at blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:1932
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:2271)
    at viewAutorun (blaze.js?hash=f33d3df…:1931)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js?hash=997515f…:339)
    at Tracker.Computation._recompute (tracker.js?hash=997515f…:358)
aldeed_autoform.js?hash=62240ad…:2037 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeEmptyStrings' of undefined
    at Object.autoFormGetFormValues [as getFormValues] (aldeed_autoform.js?hash=62240ad…:2037)
    at autoFormRegFormCallback (aldeed_autoform.js?hash=62240ad…:6575)
    at aldeed_autoform.js?hash=62240ad…:670
    at Function._.each._.forEach (underscore.js?hash=cde485f…:157)
    at formPreserveConstructor.FormPreserve._retrieveRegisteredDocuments (aldeed_autoform.js?hash=62240ad…:669)
    at Object.callback (aldeed_autoform.js?hash=62240ad…:628)
    at pollProviders (reload.js?hash=02487cd…:180)
    at Object.Reload._migrate (reload.js?hash=02487cd…:198)
    at reload.js?hash=02487cd…:252
    at underscore.js?hash=cde485f…:717
```

> **NOTE**: Any help would be deeply appreciated and rewarded.

Comment: It can stay in the corresponding js file of the template. I have mine there and have run into 0 issues. On a separate note, is your autoform type ```insert``` or are you using ```method``` / ```method-update```. If you're passing the doc to the server then you can completely do away with the need for hooks to do the manipulation on the client side.

Comment: type = "insert";

Comment: Did you read this passage of the manual? => https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#formtodoc-formtomodifier-and-doctoform